# Alert selected drop-down list item of looping from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a looping drop-down using select tag fetch from database. I want to alert value whenever select item is selected or change. But the problem is it only alert the first row of select item (orange box). How to make every select is change, it shall alert the value (blue box)?

[image: Display select]

```
<select id="select_price" name="select_price" class="form-control" onchange="demo()">
    <option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
    <?php
        for ($countPrice=1; $countPrice<=10; $countPrice++) {
          echo "<option value='"; echo $countPrice; echo "'>";
          echo $countPrice;
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;( ";
          echo number_format((float)$countPrice*$row_display['price'], 2, '.', '');
          echo ")</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

This is jQuery for onChange

```
function demo() {
    alert($("#select_price").children("option").filter(":selected").val());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Encode the jQuery script into an .js file. You can call it in front-side using `<script>`. In this programming below the event is triggered dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select_price")
        .change(function () {
            $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
               alert( $( this ).text() );
            });
        });
});
```

If `.text()` doesn't work try `.val()`.

Comment: code revised, has missing a parenthesis. Please, try now.

Comment: It trigger the alert . But only alert the value from the first row (orange box) when selected other row. Do I need to differentiate for each looping id/name?

Comment: Yes, because there are others id names.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this instead of demo function

```
$('#select_price').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

```
$( "select" ).change(function() {
var str = 0;
$( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
  str += Number($(this).val());
});
$( ".cakoroi" ).text( str );}) .trigger( "change" );
```

It will combine the value of selected select.